# Null Hypothesis Test

Tags: statistics

Test the null hypothesis that the mean is greater than or equal to 50.   Use a one tail and a significance level of .05.   A sample of 25 answers has a mean=45 and a variance=25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the t-test to test

$H_0: \mu = 50$

against

$H_A: \mu > 50$.

The t statistics is obtained by

$t_{eval} = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu_0}{s/\sqrt{n}}$,

in which $\mu_0$ is the mean under the hypothesis $H_0$ and $s$ is the standard deviation of the sample.

We must compare $t_{cal}$ with the critical value $t_{1-\alpha, n-1} = 0.8242$.

Clearly, we don't reject $H_0$.